# How to point my domain to a new server?

Tags: web-hosting

I have a website registered `www.somename.com` under a server **'A'**...

Now i want to upload files of the domain in a new server **'B'**

- how to start as i am new to web
  hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exact course of actions depends on the registrar you're using, but generally you must have an A record somewhere that says:

```
www.somename.com. IN A 1.2.3.4
```

you need to change that so that it reads:

```
www.somename.com. IN A 4.3.2.1
```

it also possible the www is a CNAME to another domain that has an A record. But all that you can find out from the company that you registered your domain with. ask them, or if they have web console - doi it yourself, to change the IP from server A to server B.